# Looping a Local Notification

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode, notifications

I'm working on an app at the moment.
I have triggered a notification to be sent to the user when they press a button and leave the app. 
The button also starts a timer within the app.
The notification is triggered through the button but is not sent to the user until they leave the app. 
I want this notification to be triggered everytime the user leaves the app while the timer is running. 
Currently, the code that I have written allows a notification to be sent when the start button is pressed. The PROBLEM is that the notification is only sent once. So if the user left the application a second time, the notification will not send.

1. I want to loop the notification while the timer is running. So whenever the user leaves the app while the timer is running, the notification is triggered.
2. I want to place a timer in the background that will give the user a time period to return to the app before the timer ends. --> the attach my endTimer() function to the end of that background timer.

Thanks

Code:

ViewControler.swift:

@IBAction func start(_ sender: Any) {
         startTimer()

```
}


func startTimer() {
    countdownTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector (ViewController.countdown), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    countdown()
    stopOutlet.isHidden = false
    startOutlet.isHidden = true
    //titlleLabel.isHidden = true
    sliderView.isHidden = true

    if countdownTimer .isValid {
        registerUserNotificationSettings()

    }

}


func registerUserNotificationSettings(){


    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()

    //adding title, subtitle, body and badge
    content.title = "Hey if you will not come back"
    content.subtitle = "your timer will be killed"
    content.body = ""
    content.badge = 1

    //getting the notification trigger
    //it will be called after 3 seconds
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 3, repeats: false)


    //getting the notification request
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "SimplifiedIOSNotification", content: content, trigger: trigger)

    //adding the notification to notification center
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)


}
```